# How to pass Runtime query to SqlTransform in apache beam?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to pass the Query dynamically while running the Dataflow job. I am using SQLTransform which works fine when I pass Query within code.

My use case requires passing the Query at Runtime, is it possible with `SqlTransform` in Apache Beam?

This works if I hard-code it in code.

```
String PQuery = "SELECT col1, max(col2) as max_watermark FROM PCOLLECTION GROUP BY col1";
PCollection<Row> rows1 =   rows.apply(SqlTransform.query(PQuery));
```

But with `valueProvider` input, it gives compile time error.

```
PCollection<Row> rows1 =   rows.apply(SqlTransform.query(options.getQuery()))
```

**Error**

```
The method query(String) in the type SqlTransform is not applicable for the arguments (ValueProvider<String>)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you need to get the value inside the [ValueProvider](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-functions) :

```java
PCollection<Row> rows1 = rows.apply(SqlTransform.query(options.getQuery().get()))
```

The `query` method takes a `String` as parameter, that's why you need to get the `String` value of the `ValueProvider` option.

Comment: @nikhil-suthar have you soved your issue ?
if it's the case, may you mark the answer as solved please ?

Comment: Note that ValueProviders won't work here, as the query is needed at graph construction time and influences the shape of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [FlexTemplates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) which allow dynamic graph construction (such as SqlTransform) uses based on template parameters.